# How to set Firebase security rule for read operation when user reads his/her own profile data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am developing a Flutter app and using Firebase as backend. In my app, each user needs o sign up to be able to use the app and the user's profile data is saved in a `user_profile` collection.

Each user's profile data is stored in a separate document in the collection.
The Document ID for each document is equal to the User ID, created by the Firebase Authentication when the user signs up for the first time.
And I also save the User ID in a field (named uid) in each document as well for the corresponding user.

For the security part, I want that each user may only read his/her own profile data. I set the following rule:

```
// Rules for User Profile data
match /user_profile/{any} {
  allow read: if (request.auth != null) && 
                 (resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid) && 
                 exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
```

Is it correct if I set my rules as given in the above example?
(1) The user needs to be authenticated
(2) The `uid` in the incoming request needs to be equal to the uid field in the corresponding document that the user wants to read.
(3) The document with the uid available in the request must exist in the corresponding document

I cannot make it clear to me if I am making the whole thing unnecessarily complicated. For instance, does the rule (1) do the same thing as rule (2)? While I have rules (1) and (2), does it add anything to have rule (3) as well?

Comment: Please edit the post to narrow this down to a single question.  There are three distinct questions here, which is technically off topic for Stack Overflow and could be closed.  You can determine the correctness of your rules by running client app code against it to see if it works the way you expect.  That's not really something we can help you with,  If you have code that doesn't work the way you expect, please explain that along with your client app code that makes the query.

Comment: This is a single question. You asked me to update it and I wrote 2 new questions. You seem to write the same comment without even reading the question!

Comment: I count three questions here.  1) Is it correct if I set my rules as given in the above example? 2) does the rule (1) do the same thing as rule (2)? 3) While I have rules (1) and (2), does it add anything to have rule (3) as well?

Comment: All those statements are connected to each other. The underlying question is the same. How should the security rule be set for the use case defined in the question.

Comment: Rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only triggered when client code makes a query.  Without seeing your query, along with an explanation of what these rules are supposed to do, and how they aren't working the way you expect, there's not much we can do to help. Again, we can't determine for you if the rules are correct - you can test that yourself by actually making queries again them and checking if the result is what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the following elements in your question:

1. The user's profile data is saved in a `user_profile` collection
2. The document ID for each (user's profile) document is equal to the User ID
3. You want that each user may only read his/her own profile data

the following **read** security rule should do the trick:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'user_profile' collection
    match /user_profile/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, since the document ID for each (user's profile) document is equal to the `userId` you don't need to use the field containing the `userId` in the security rule: The wildcard expression `{userId}` makes the `userId` variable available in rules, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see your point. What about the exists(..) function..? Does it add anything on top of the other 2 rules or does it become obsolete?

Comment: The [`exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.exists) method checks if a document exists. In your specific case (as expressed by the three points at the top of the anwser) you don't need to use this method at all. If there is a match with this security rule it means that the user doc with Id = userID exists => therefore you just want to check that the user who is reading it is the user corresponding the document ID.